# Is there a way to optimize my code for converting from an array to a 2d coordinate system?

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, assign

I'm trying to make a heatmap in Matlab. The values passed out from my program are stored in a large, one dimensional array. So, the point 4th element on a 9 element array would be (1,2) and the 9th point would be (3,3).(1,1) would be the first element. A value is stored in each element.

Once in matlab, I want to convert this array to a matrix, so that I can use imagesc() to show how high or low each element of the array is in an x,y coordinate system.

My code works, but I feel it takes too long to run for the task.

In my code, x.index is the array subscript (x.index(1) would be the very first element of the array that the code output.)

I pass in the total number of elements in the array, and take the square root to get the x and y bounds. I named this variable dim.

grid and x are tables that contains integers.

```
dim = sqrt(x.raycount());
grid = table();

a = zeros(dim,dim)

for i = 1:height(x)
    rem = mod(x.index(i),dim);
    grid.yvalue(i,1) = (x.index(i)-rem)/dim;
    grid.xvalue(i,1) = rem;
    nloc = x.nloc(i)
    grid.nloc(i,1) = nloc;
    a(grid.xvalue(i),grid.yvalue(i)) = grid.nloc(i);
end
```

Comment: Your question /  code is not very clear in regards to its intent. Do you really need the `grid` table or is it just auxiliary in the process to get matrix `a`? (Also, is `nloc` an integer or a double value? If the second, the grid doesn't contain just integers.)

Comment: Extending the above comment, please edit your question to clarify whether you need `grid` or not, don't just answer in comments. Furthermore, as a note, it is always easier for us to help you when you provide a minimal & reproducible example: [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need the `grid` table and as your enumeration is column-major (as for a 9-element `x` your 4th element should be assigned in position (1,2) of `a` matrix) you can do it in one line as:

```
sideLength=sqrt(length(x.nloc));
a = reshape(x.nloc(x.index(x.index)),[sideLength,sideLength]);
```

This is if you are sure you have a square grid. If you have a rectangular grid instead, use `[sidelength1,sidelength2]` as the second argument to
[reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)
command.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard of the reshape function. I was able to reduce the code to:

    dim = sqrt(x.raycount(1));
    table1 = zeros(1,x.raycount(1));

    for i = 1:height(x)
        table1(x.index(i)) = x.nloc(i);
    end

    a = reshape(table1,dim,dim);

Comment: Your welcome. I think I misunderstood, so in the linear indexing the subscript is obtained by x.index. In that case, try as one liner this:
`sideLength=sqrt(length(x.nloc));` and 
`a = reshape(x.nloc(x.index(x.index)),[sideLength,sideLength]);` If this is acceptable, I'll incorporate it in the above answer.

Comment: @JacobShirley is your question answered or is there anything more?